# Dynamic Content....why isn't it working?

Tags: php

Okay I want to apologize in advance because I'm having trouble articulating what the root cause of the problem is with this site that I'm attempting to build. So if I'm way off in outer space...=/

Anyways, the first issue I'm having is that when I attempted to fix an issue with "include" function in php I'm getting this error (below) the reason why I was tampering with it at all was because my navs aren't working. I keep getting a 404 whenever I attempt to leave the index.php page.

> Warning: include(/home/content/22/10350022/html/../Setup.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/22/10350022/html/index.php on line 6

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/content/22/10350022/html/../Setup.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/22/10350022/html/index.php on line 6

Here is the code from index.php, setup, and navs:

Index.php ---below

```
       > > <?php
// Setup Document:
//include (1) - forces the site to load the file one time but we're not going to include set up file more than once

define('APP_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . "/../");
include(APP_PATH . "Setup.php");

if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] ==! ''){
   $pg =$_GET['page'];
} else {
   $pg = 'Home';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/styles.css">

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #039;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class ="header">
            <?php include('Template/header.php');?>
     </div>   
    <div class ="main_Nav">
          <?php include('Template/main_Nav.php');?>     
    </div>

    <div class ="main_Content">

        <?php include('Content/'.$pg.'.php');?>
        <?php #$Home = "SELECT body FROM Pages WHERE Id=1";
            #$d = '$Home, $conn';
                #if ($d == false) {
                    #echo "FAILURE".mysql_error($conn);
                #}
        ?>
<div class ="main_Footer">
        <?php include('Template/footer.php');?> 
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Some stuff is commented out on purpose so I could work on this issue.

Navs below --

```
<?php
## Main Navigation Document
include('/Config/setup.php');
?>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="FreeStuff">Free Stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="Blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Finally - setup -- some info is blacked out obviously and some stuff is commented out on purpose

```
<?php

    ## Setup Document

    //Host - location of database on server etc
    //username
    //pswd
    //database name

    //connection variables
    $host = "";
    $user = "test";
    $pwd = "";
    $db = "test";

    //connection info

    $conn = mysqli_connect ($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
    if ($conn ==false) {
        echo "connection has failed";
    }

    //fetching the title of pages
    #$sql = "SELECT title FROM pages WHERE Id=2";

    //da warnings

    #$r = '$sql,$conn';
    #   echo $r;
    #   echo "sucess!";
    // return

    #if ($r == false) {
    #   echo "FAILURE".mysql_error($conn);
    #}

    ?>
```

Originally I was just using **include('/Config/setup.php');** which works. But whenever I attempt to navigate to content featured in my navs bar...i get a 404 error. Now this should only change the content box -- the rest of the page should remain static. `<?php include('Content/'.$pg.'.php');?>` Which is what I think I'm doing here. Or at least I hope it is lol. $pg is the string 4(Home) and unless page is otherwise defined it will be defaulted to home. At least that is what I THINK I wrote above.

my file structure just really fast is this:

...root folder on FTP
-content
-config
-images
-Css
-templates
-Stats
-Roodyinfo

Now this path it keeps asking for...does that have to do with my hosting service? Cause it seems like its saying I have to define an ABSOLUTE path???

All help is welcome and appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I bet `include('/Config/setup.php');` has never worked, because that would be an absolute path. Try utilizing PHPs `include_path`, or make all your include paths relative to the webserver main directory using `include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/Config/setup.php");` if all else fails.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all the files you need in the same directory and use require('filename'); with no paths.